# Automate custom Django management command with crontab, within virtualenv

Tags: django, cron, manage.py

I am trying to run a custom management command on my Django app, installed under a virtualenvironment.

This task is supposed to run once every minute, and I cannot quite figure out why it doesn't work.

Here's what I have in my crontab:

```
*/1 * * * * /home/myuser/.virtualenvs/myvirtualenv/bin/python /home/myuser/myapp/manage.py mycommand --settings=myapp.settings
```

This won't work, even if I see the command executing once a minute in `/var/log/syslog`, but it must be failing because it produces no effect.

If I just copy and run the same command, everything goes smooth.

I then tried running instead an external bash script, which again perfectly works if I run it manually:

```
*/1 * * * * source /home/myuser/myapp/myscript
```

The script activates the virtualenv and runs the management command.
Again, no results.

I am a bit lost, as I've searched around thoroughly and I am completely stuck, as apparently no error messages show up anywhere.

Comment: What logging goes your management command do? It'd be worth capturing as much as you can to see where it's blowing up, else you're effectively debugging while blind.

Comment: Also what environment is this running on? VPS/shared hosting?

Comment: My command does a fair share of logging, but I can't see any of it unless I run the command manually. This leads me to thinking that I must have screwed something up with cron, rather than the command.

It is running on a VPS yes.

Answer (score 1):

The problem might be that `myapp.settings` isn't on your Python path. I would try changing directory first:

```
*/1 * * * * cd /home/mysuser/myapp && /home/myuser/.virtualenvs/myvirtualenv/bin/python manage.py mycommand --settings=myapp.settings
```

Comment: Nope, that did not help.

Comment: Redirect the stdout and stderr to a file e.g. append `>> /path/to/logfile 2>&1` to the command. Then you might see what the problem is in the log file.

Answer (score 0):

After fiddling with crontabs myself in one of my projects, I started to use [Celery](http://www.celeryproject.org) (more specifically Celery Beat) for my periodic tasks. It is only a little more complicated to set up (You will need a message broker e.g. Redis) but it's much more powerful afterwards.

Even if you do not use the asynchronous task execution, the ease of managing cron jobs is worth the setup. Jobs can simply be defined right in your project's code by the usage of a function decorator, no need to edit the crontab on the server.

For managing the Celery worker(s) and the celery beat process, I would recommend the usage of [supervisord](http://supervisord.org)

Comment: I fear I will have to go that way as well. I spent some 2 days already trying to get this command run via cron, but it just doesn't seem the right way of doing it.
Celery on the other hand was scaring me, exactly because of the reasons you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

The reason there are no error messages showing up is because cron sends them by *email* to the postbox of the user whose crontab is being executed.

- If you created the cronjobs with `crontab -e`, this will be the postbox of the user you are logged in with.
- If you created the cronjobs with `sudo crontab -e`, this will be the postbox of the root user.

To read the emails you must set up an email server and client. For this, `postfix` (which is the server) and `mutt` (the client) are very popular options and their installations are covered in many good tutorials.

Make sure to differentiate between your logged-in user's postbox, which is opened via `mutt` and the root user's postbox, which needs `sudo mutt`.

Once you have this set up, debugging will be a lot easier.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. My code was not able to get any variables from the settings file. It was fixed when I changed directory and activated the virtual environment.

```
*/1 * * * * cd /home/myuser/myapp && source /home/myuser/.virtualenvs/myvirtualenv/bin/activate && /home/myuser/.virtualenvs/myvirtualenv/bin/python /home/myuser/myapp/manage.py mycommand --settings=myapp.settings
```

should work in your case.